# MVC 2 - How to exclude multple columns in the create method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-2-validation

How can I exclude multiple columns when creating a new customer?  The other column is the date that the record was created - called customer_dt.

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "customer_id")] Customer customer)
{
    /* Do something here ... */
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may provide each field as a comma-separated list. For example:

```
 [Bind(Exclude="Customer_Id, Name,Description,Active")]
```